# backgroundColor not working on View

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to set a background color of a view.
I set everything in here:

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
  import { View, StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native';
  export default class Login extends Component{
    render(){
      return(
         <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text>
            Hello.
          </Text>
         </View>
      );
    }
  }

 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   container:{
       flex: 1,
       flexDirection: 'column',
       alignItems: 'center',
       justifyContent: 'center',
       backgroundColor: 'rgba(79, 81, 140, 1.0)',
     }
 });
```

The problem is that the view is staying with white color.
I tried to add text to the view to see if it's background color is changing and it does.
How can I set the background color of the view to be a color I choose?
I searched the net but couldn't find anything..

Comment: Add alignSelf :'stretch'

Comment: @WilomGfx Thanks, shouldn't flex do that ?

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/ryqWfpXCe  Your exact code is working with purple background

Answer (score 5):

Remove flex:1 from the container style, it will work.

Comment: could you elaborate why removing flex: 1 works in this case?

Answer (score 4):

Your width and height are 0 that's why it is not shown. You need to set width and height to something for it to be shown.

Answer (score 2):

Dannie's answer is correct.

`flexDirection: 'column'` might flex the height, but it won't affect the width, even if there's content width a perceivable width.

`alignItems` doesn't do anything either until the flex container is wider than the content inside your container.

flexbox in react-native isn't perfect yet, and there will be points in your development where you'd want to do things like this with the actual dimensions of your screen.
You could set the width of your login screen like this:

```
const dimScreen= Dimensions.get("screen");
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   container:{
       flex: 1,
       flexDirection: 'column',
       alignItems: 'center',
       justifyContent: 'center',
       backgroundColor: 'rgba(79, 81, 140, 1.0)',
       width: dimScreen.width,
   }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Give view's height 100% and remove flex:1

```
    <View style={{backgroundColor: colors.cyan, height: '100%'}}>

    </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add number in your styling code

```html
const dimScreen= Dimensions.get("screen");
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   container:{
       flex: 1,
       flexDirection: 'column',
       alignItems: 'center',
       justifyContent: 'center',
       backgroundColor: 'rgba(79, 81, 140, 1.0)',
       width: 200,
       height:200
   }
});
```

And FYI for responsive design, you can use [Responsive Design](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-responsive-dimensions)

Answer (score 0):

May be you have a View wrapping your Login in your `App.js` file.